# Swift error: Could not find an overload for '-' that accepts the supplied arguments

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to translate existing lines of Objective-C code into Swift.  The following is what I have.

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

let kWorldWidth = 6324
let kWorldHeight = 620
let kWorldTileSize = 62
let kWorldCenterX = 3162
let kWorldCenterY = 310

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var scene : SKScene?
    var backgroundTextures = NSMutableArray()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadWorldTiles()
    }

    func loadWorldTiles() {
        let tileAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named:"Tiles")
        backgroundTextures = NSMutableArray(capacity: 1020)
        for var y = 0; y < 10; y++ {
            for var x = 0; x < 102; x++ {
                let tileNumber = (y * 102) + x
                let tileNode = SKSpriteNode(texture:tileAtlas.textureNamed(String(format:"%d",tileNumber)))
                var position: CGPoint = CGPointMake(x*kWorldTileSize-kWorldCenterX+0.5*kWorldTileSize,kWorldHeight-y*kWorldTileSize-kWorldCenterY-0.5*kWorldTileSize)
                tileNode.position = position
                backgroundTextures.addObject(tileNode)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error where I have var position.  The error message is Could not find an overload for '-' that accepts the supplied arguments.  Running a search, I find that you will get this error when you don't explicitly declare variable types.  If I create integer variables like

```
var xval:CGFloat = x*kWorldTileSize-kWorldCenterX+0.5*kWorldTileSize
var yval:CGFloat = kWorldHeight-y*kWorldTileSize-kWorldCenterY-0.5*kWorldTileSize
var position: CGPoint = CGPointMake(xval,yval)
```

I still get the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Muchos thankos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type inference is making all your constant declarations and for loop counter variables of type `Int`, since you are using `Int` literals.  You cannot inherently do math with mixed types like `Int`, `Double`, and `CGFloat`.  Also, you are ultimately trying to create a `CGFloat` type, so it's best to use that explicitly for your constants like so:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

let kWorldWidth: CGFloat = 6324
let kWorldHeight: CGFloat = 620
let kWorldTileSize: CGFloat = 62
let kWorldCenterX: CGFloat = 3162
let kWorldCenterY: CGFloat = 310

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var scene : SKScene?
    var backgroundTextures = NSMutableArray()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadWorldTiles()
    }

    func loadWorldTiles() {
        let tileAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named:"Tiles")
        backgroundTextures = NSMutableArray(capacity: 1020)
        for var y = 0; y < 10; y++ {
            for var x = 0; x < 102; x++ {
                let tileNumber = (y * 102) + x
                let tileNode = SKSpriteNode(texture:tileAtlas.textureNamed(String(format:"%d",tileNumber)))
                var position: CGPoint = CGPointMake(CGFloat(x)*kWorldTileSize-kWorldCenterX+0.5*kWorldTileSize,kWorldHeight-CGFloat(y)*kWorldTileSize-kWorldCenterY-0.5*kWorldTileSize)
                tileNode.position = position
                backgroundTextures.addObject(tileNode)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your x and y values are also causing problems.  Try CGFloat(x) and CGFloat(y).

Comment: No.  That doesn't change a thing.

Comment: Fixes it for me.  I'll update the code in my answer so you can copy paste and see what I mean.